# after bundler installed with specific version why version of bundler did not change?

Tags: ruby, bundler, gem-bundler

I got following error for bundle

> Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "bundler":   In
>   Gemfile:
>       bundler (~> 1.15)
>
> Current Bundler version:
>       bundler (2.0.1) This Gemfile requires a different version of Bundler. Perhaps you need to update Bundler by running `gem install
>   bundler`?
>
> Could not find gem 'bundler (~> 1.15)' in any of the relevant sources:
>   the local ruby installation

then I tried to downgrade the bundler version with

> $ gem install bundler -v '~> 1.7.0' Fetching: bundler-1.7.15.gem 
>   (100%) Successfully installed bundler-1.7.15 Parsing documentation for
>   bundler-1.7.15 Installing ri documentation for bundler-1.7.15 Done
>   installing documentation for bundler after 1 seconds 1 gem installed

but when I recheck the bundler version with

> bundler --version

it still said Bundler version 2.0.1

Answer (score 3):

The default bundler version on your system is still `2.0.1`. If you need to use the downloaded version `1.7.15`, you would have to run `bundle _1.7.15_ install`. You could also check if that version was successfully installed on your system using `bundle _1.7.15_ -v` 
In either case, if you get the error `Could not find command "_1.7.15_"`, then that means that the bundler version `_1.7.15_` has not been installed on your system.
Additionally, these links may help you:

- [Run specific version of bundler](https://makandracards.com/makandra/9741-run-specific-version-of-bundler)
- [Downgrade Bundler in RVM](https://makandracards.com/makandra/29161-downgrade-bundler-in-rvm)

Comment: Also, if the OP doesn't want to use 2.0.1 at all, they can also run `gem uninstall bundler` and choose to uninstall the 2.0.1 version (they may need to reshim if using a ruby version manager)

Answer (score 0):

Try updating bundle with `bundler update bundler` and run the `bundle update` again. It solved my problem the last time.